# Tips for keeping a motor in sync?

Tags: pi-2, electronics

So I got this [motor](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2941), and I need to be able to control its angle with a raspberry pi; its okay if there is a little inaccuracy, but I don't want it to lose precision over time.

Any tips on how to periodically resynchronize it (it is pulling a string in a motion [sort of like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_motion).)

Any general advice on motor synchronization would be helpful.

Comment: That looks like a 5V device so you'll need something in the middle.

Comment: @goldilocks I know (I bought a MOSFET.)

Comment: Dunno if this might be useful: https://www.adafruit.com/products/820 -> If that doesn't make sense, it probably isn't.

Comment: @goldilocks it does. Will a MOSFET transistor work?

Comment: I do not know, but I'd think so -- transistors should respond on a far, far finer time scale than motors.  Adafruit has a tutorial about using a darlington array with stepper motors, and this seems like much the same idea except you need more current.  But I'm not an electrician -- you might want to ask on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or just try it, I can't see how anything is going to get damaged (did I mention not being an electrician?).

Comment: @goldilocks I will at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add some sort of feedback.  A rotary encoder [like this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11102) could be attached to the other end of the shaft. You would then need to have the Raspberry Pi continuously monitor that input to know the position.

If you need continuous rotation and angular precision I you probably should look at a stepper motor instead of a DC motor or servo. With a stepper you can control the rotation in precise increments (steps).

Answer (score -1):

It's a servo.  It goes to the commanded angle.  There is need to resynchronise (unless you strip the gears).

You command an angle by sending electrical pulses 50 times per second.  If the pulse is 1.5 ms long it goes to the centre, if the pulse is shorter it goes to an angle more counterclockwise, if the pulse is longer it goes to an angle more clockwise.

The amount of turn in degrees from most counterclockwise to most clockwise and range of allowable pulse widths varies from servo to servo.  You will need to calibrate your software against the servo.

Comment: Not a servo, its a motor in a servo body.

Comment: If you look at the link provided, the text states that it is *not* a servo. It looks like a servo but with the feedback circuit removed.

Comment: @PyRulez  My mistake.  However in that case why don't you by a servo?

Comment: Because [that one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2442) is $4 more from the same source? >_<

Comment: @goldilocks If he does opt for a servo it should be a regular one rather than continuous rotation.  A servo will likely be cheaper and more reliable and easier to implement than buying a motor driver board and  encoders and such like to get over DC motor positioning problems.

Comment: Looking at the reciprocating motion machine from from the OP, you do probably need something with continuous rotation.  I'd think you could figure out exactly how many pulses of a certain width will turn it how far -- but then I don't know if it will be possible to control it that precisely with the pi.

Comment: @goldilocks Can't tell from the question what sort of pull/push distance is involved.  By the way continuous rotation servos don't work on pulses (as a stepper would).  The pulse length instead of determining the angle determines the speed of rotation.  You'd have the same problem determining the current position as you would with a DC motor.

Comment: I have a continuous rotation servo (FS5103R) and it certainly does work on pulses -- looking around this seems to be the norm.  1.5 ms is stopped, +/- that is speed and direction. So, eg., 3 * 1.62 ms then 1.5 ms might rotate it X degrees.  Dunno what difference load will make.

Comment: @goldilocks It doesn't work on pulses like a stepper - one pulse, one step.  The pulse width just says go at this speed, you can send 20 or 60 or whatever of those pulses a second, as long as the pulse is the same width it will rotate at the same speed.

Comment: So it would be more like pulse width W for time T, which is a variation on the same theme -- but still probably not very feasible.   Thinking about the "reciprocating machine" and "pulling a string" back and forth a regular servo would be the best *if* you have room for attaching the right size gear wheel...